# Transaction API doesn't work with the payment

Tags: actions-on-google

Since two weeks we are trying to implement transaction api v3. with Google
payment option. Once we did a transaction the receipt has been displayed.
When we pressed "order" button we got confirmation that the transaction is
being confirmed but in developer Dotpay panel there were no visible
payments.
After a few transactions action stopped displaying the receipt and it
informed that "something went wrong. Try again later". When we removed googlePaymentOption from
TransactionDecision the receipt has been displayed but we were still not
able to make any transactions. 
It lasted for a few days and after that we were able to make transactions again but there were
still no payments visible.

Can you please have a look?

Hereby you can find our transaction logs:

````
{
  "conversationToken": "[\"_actions_on_google\",\"podsumowanie\",\"rezerwuj_dostawe\",\"zmien_zamowienie_lista\",\"start_index\",\"modyfikuj_koszyk\",\"dodaj_produkt\"]",
  "expectUserResponse": true,
  "expectedInputs": [{
    "inputPrompt": {
      "richInitialPrompt": {
        "items": [{
          "simpleResponse": {
            "textToSpeech": "Transaction Decision Placeholder."
          }
        }]
      }
    },
    "possibleIntents": [{
      "intent": "actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION",
      "inputValueData": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.transactions.v3.TransactionDecisionValueSpec",
        "order": {
          "merchantOrderId": "9g1blj8rmvo",
          "userVisibleOrderId": "9g1blj8rmvo",
          "buyerInfo": {
            "email": "janedoe@gmail.com",
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "displayName": "Jane Doe"
          },
          "createTime": "2020-06-09T14:02:08.812Z",
          "lastUpdateTime": "2020-06-09T14:02:08.812Z",
          "transactionMerchant": {
            "id": "book_store_1",
            "name": "Book Store"
          },
          "contents": {
            "lineItems": [{
              "id": "memoirs_4",
              "name": "Our memoirs",
              "priceAttributes": [{
                "type": "REGULAR",
                "name": "Item Price",
                "state": "ACTUAL",
                "amount": {
                  "currencyCode": "PLN",
                  "amountInMicros": "1000000"
                },
                "taxIncluded": true
              }, {
                "type": "TOTAL",
                "name": "Total Price",
                "state": "ACTUAL",
                "amount": {
                  "currencyCode": "PLN",
                  "amountInMicros": "1000000"
                },
                "taxIncluded": true
              }],
              "notes": ["Special introduction by author."],
              "purchase": {
                "quantity": 1
              }
            }]
          },
          "priceAttributes": [{
            "type": "SUBTOTAL",
            "name": "Subtotal",
            "state": "ESTIMATE",
            "amount": {
              "currencyCode": "PLN",
              "amountInMicros": "1000000"
            },
            "taxIncluded": true
          }, {
            "type": "DELIVERY",
            "name": "Delivery",
            "state": "ACTUAL",
            "amount": {
              "currencyCode": "PLN"
            },
            "taxIncluded": true
          }, {
            "type": "TAX",
            "name": "Tax",
            "state": "ESTIMATE",
            "amount": {
              "currencyCode": "PLN"
            },
            "taxIncluded": true
          }, {
            "type": "TOTAL",
            "name": "Total Price",
            "state": "ESTIMATE",
            "amount": {
              "currencyCode": "PLN",
              "amountInMicros": "1000000"
            },
            "taxIncluded": true
          }],
          "followUpActions": [{
            "type": "VIEW_DETAILS",
            "title": "View details",
            "openUrlAction": {
              "url": "http://example.com"
            }
          }, {
            "type": "CALL",
            "title": "Call us",
            "openUrlAction": {
              "url": "tel:+16501112222"
            }
          }, {
            "type": "EMAIL",
            "title": "Email us",
            "openUrlAction": {
              "url": "mailto:person@example.com"
            }
          }],
          "termsOfServiceUrl": "http://www.example.com",
          "note": "The Memoir collection",
          "purchase": {
            "status": "CREATED",
            "type": "RETAIL",
            "returnsInfo": {
              "daysToReturn": 1,
              "policyUrl": "http://www.example.com"
            },
            "fulfillmentInfo": {
              "id": "FULFILLMENT_SERVICE_ID",
              "fulfillmentType": "DELIVERY",
              "expectedFulfillmentTime": {
                "timeIso8601": "2025-09-25T18:00:00.877Z"
              },
              "price": {
                "type": "REGULAR",
                "name": "Delivery Price",
                "state": "ACTUAL",
                "amount": {
                  "currencyCode": "PLN"
                },
                "taxIncluded": true
              },
              "fulfillmentContact": {
                "email": "janedoe@gmail.com",
                "firstName": "Jane",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "displayName": "Jane Doe"
              }
            },
            "purchaseLocationType": "ONLINE_PURCHASE",
            "userVisibleStatusLabel": "CREATED"
          }
        },
        "orderOptions": {
          "userInfoOptions": {
            "userInfoProperties": ["EMAIL"]
          }
        },
        "paymentParameters": {
          "googlePaymentOption": {
            "facilitationSpec": "{\"apiVersion\":2,\"apiVersionMinor\":0,\"merchantInfo\":{\"merchantName\":\"Frisco\"},\"allowedPaymentMethods\":[{\"type\":\"CARD\",\"parameters\":{\"allowedAuthMethods\":[\"PAN_ONLY\"],\"allowedCardNetworks\":[\"MASTERCARD\",\"VISA\"]},\"tokenizationSpecification\":{\"type\":\"PAYMENT_GATEWAY\",\"parameters\":{\"gateway\":\"dotpay\",\"gatewayMerchantId\":\"705777\"}}}],\"transactionInfo\":{\"totalPriceStatus\":\"FINAL\",\"totalPrice\":\"1.00\",\"currencyCode\":\"PLN\"}}"
          }
        },
        "presentationOptions": {
          "actionDisplayName": "PLACE_ORDER"
        }
      }
    }],
    "speechBiasingHints": ["$usun", "$dalej", "$events", "$wroc", "$product", "$deleteProduct", "$sztuka", "$dodaj", "$ilosc", "$produkty", "$deleteOrder"]
  }],
  "responseMetadata": {
    "status": {
      "message": "Success (200)"
    },
    "queryMatchInfo": {
      "queryMatched": true,
      "intent": "777d19a8-c59a-46d2-ae22-212827b5726e"
    }
  }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Google is working with a limited number of partners that can get access to the production Google Pay API. If you're not one of those partners, you're welcome to read the documentation and test the integration using the sandbox environment.

https://developers.google.com/assistant/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-gpay

If you are indeed one of these partners, please reach out to your Google contact.